# Do Linux drivers depend on Linux kernel?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My external bluetooth adapter is not working in this version of Ubuntu, but it is working very well in Ubuntu 12.x versions. So i downloaded and installed Ubuntu 12.x kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Still my external bluetooth is not working. Does the kernel store linux drivers? Then how can I find driver for specific hardware for Linux? (Like external bluetooth device)
How to solve this?

Comment: Please boot with normal Ubuntu 14.04 kernel and add output of `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: Downloading and installing an old kernel is not sufficient. Ubuntu will boot using the latest default kernel unless you manually choose to boot from a different kernel from GRUB advanced menu or change the GRUB default as described by Serg below.

Answer (score 2):

You are right: Linux kernel comes with the drivers (aka `modules`), and if some of the drivers do not work, you may try installing or booting (if you have) a different kernel.  For instance, on 14.04LTS, kernel 3.19 I had a problem with the Virtual box kernel module. But with 14.04LTS and kernel 3.13 there is no problem. *Notice, however, that if the Linux kernel does not contain a driver for your device, you may need to find it from your manufacturer or from open source repositories.*

To try a different kernel, first find out what kernel you are using with the `uname -r` command in terminal. Then reboot the machine, chose <kbd>Advanced Options for Ubuntu</kbd>, and choose any option that has a different kernel number (than shown with `uname -r` command ) and not displaying <kbd>( recovery mode )</kbd>.

If your bluetooth donlge works with an older kernel, it's definitely a driver issue.

To tell Ubuntu to boot with your desired kernel, first remember the item you chose from the <kbd>Advanced Options menu</kbd>.  For instance, I want to always boot with 3.13 kernel, and I chose to boot with <kbd>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-62-generic</kbd>.

Next, run this command:

```
awk '/menuentry/ && /class/ {count++; print count-1"****"$0 }' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | less
```

Remember the number next to your desired entry.

Finally, run  the command bellow. *REPLACE X   in GRUB_DEFAULT=X with the number you remembered*.

```
sudo sed -i  's/GRUB_DEFAULT=0/GRUB_DEFAULT=X/g' /etc/default/grub; sudo update-grub
```

Now, when you reboot, you should be booting with older, working kernel.

Comment: I am sure it is possible to use that bluetooth on new kernels ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 True that ! It's would be surprising if a newer kernel got module removed. Here I'm trying to give OP a method to just make it all work again.

Comment: I am already tried it! Still not working.

Comment: @BuvaneshKumar  Have you tried the adapter on other machines ? Also, please post output of `lsusb` as Pilot6 asked in the comments.

Comment: It's my lsusb result: Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub &  i tried in another Ubuntu PC too.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:14db Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub